# varargs lambda gives illegal instruction - bug in clang or UB?

Tags: c++, variadic-functions, clang++

The following code gives Illegal instruction under clang, but works under gcc. Is it a bug in clang or is there some kind of UB?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

int main() {
    std::function<void(const std::string&, const std::string&)> fn = [](...) { std::cout << "ok\n"; };
    fn("a", "b");
}
```

Comment: Passing `std::string` to C-ellipsis is suspect.

Comment: From [C-ellipisis](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variadic_arguments): *"However, non-POD class types (until C++11)class types with an eligible non-trivial copy constructor, an eligible non-trivial move constructor, or a non-trivial destructor, together with scoped enumerations (since C++11), are conditionally-supported in potentially-evaluated calls with implementation-defined semantics"*

Comment: works in MSVC and clang-CL as well.

Comment: @RichardCritten: `printf("some_format", std::string("..."));` might have the same issue. passing object as `std::string` to C-ellipsis is conditionally supported, so not portable (no standard guaranty). I don't know guaranty from compiler for that.

Comment: Live demo (simplified): https://godbolt.org/z/c7Y986s44. Clang generated an _undefined instruction_ for `main`.

Comment: @lav: `auto fn = [](...) { std::cout << "ok\n"; }; fn("a", "b");` should work as expected though. (no longer `std::string` involved). (`fn(std::string("a"), std::string("b"))` should still be problematic though).

Comment: @DanielLangr: and even [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/v5nxessvd) for compilation error (accepted by gcc/msvc [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/bcf4e55Eq)).

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes, it seems that _implementation-defined semantics_ with Clang actually means that this it is not supported at all.

Comment: So clang chose to abort at runtime explicitly. [](auto...) works (as it produces a parameter pack).

Comment: It would be nice if clang produced a compile error in this case.

Answer (score 1):

As @Jarod42 commented, passing a non-trivial object to [C-ellipsis](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variadic_arguments) has implementation defined semantics. Clang choose to abort in this case and it's normal.

To avoid the problem, one can use a lambda with a [parameter pack](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

int main() {
    std::function<void(const std::string&, const std::string&)> fn = [](auto&&...) { std::cout << "ok\n"; };
    fn("a", "b");
}
```

It can be useful e.g. for default dummy callbacks:

```
constexpr auto DEFAULT_CALLBACK = [](auto&&...) {};
```